# In ormlite, How can I have a foriegn field and a field column?

Tags: java, sql, ormlite

My Entity is something like this.

```
@Data
public class Comment implements Persistable<Long>, CBHistoryTable
{
    @Id
    private Long tid;
    // sid and pid is required for serialized to json
    @DatabaseField
    private Long pid;
    @DatabaseField
    private Long sid;

    @DatabaseField(foreign = true, foreignColumnName = "sid", columnName = "sid")
    private Article article;

    @DatabaseField(foreign = true, foreignColumnName = "pid", columnName = "tid")
    private Comment parent;
}
```

When I insert, will cause the SQL Syntax Exception, `Column 'sid' specified twice`.
In ormlite table config, both of `sid` and `article` are considered as a column with the same name.

How Can I achieve this ?

**EDIT**

Here is my Article Entity

```
@Data
@DatabaseTable(daoClass = ArticleServiceImpl.class)
public class Article implements Persistable<Long>, CBHistoryTable
{
    @Id
    @SerializedName("SID")
    private Long sid;

    @SerializedName("SN")
    @DatabaseField
    private String sn;

    @ForeignCollectionField(foreignFieldName = "article")
    private Collection<Comment> comments = Sets.newHashSet();
}
```

Comment: Why both `columnName` attribute of `Common` & `Article` is `sid`?

Comment: I updated my question, the sid of parent is my mistake

Comment: I think you need to change `sid` column name either of `Long sid;` or `columnName` attribute value of `Article` to a proper name. As database column name shouldn't same in same table.

Comment: In jpa, this is works,but I try to achieve this in ormlite.The column name is make sense. I just want to expose the foriegn id in field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You change your question so last answer does't work anymore, try that  and tell me if it is what you are looking for :

```
@Data
public class Comment implements Persistable<Long>, CBHistoryTable
{
    @Id
    private Long tid;
    // sid and pid is required for serialized to json
    private Long pid;
    private Long sid;

    @DatabaseField(canbenull = true, foreign = true, foreignColumnName = "sid")
    private Article article;

    @DatabaseField(canbenull = true, foreign = true, foreignColumnName = "tid")
    private Comment parent;

    @ForeignCollectionField(foreignFieldName = "parent")
    private Collection<Comment> comments = Sets.newHashSet();

    public void setArticle(Article article) {
        this.article = article;
        sid=article.getSid();
    }

    public void setParent(Comment parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
        pid=comment.getTid();
    }
}

@Data
@DatabaseTable(daoClass = ArticleServiceImpl.class)
public class Article implements Persistable<Long>, CBHistoryTable
{
    @Id
    @SerializedName("SID")
    private Long sid;

    @SerializedName("SN")
    private String sn;

    @ForeignCollectionField(foreignFieldName = "article")
    private Collection<Comment> comments = Sets.newHashSet();
}
```

Comment: I don't understand, can you show me the code ? Thank you

Comment: Sorry, in my question, I ignored the `@DatabaseField` for normal field.Actually, they got a default `@DatabaseField` annotation.So, your code still cause the same exception. :<

Comment: Ok why do you need to call the article and parent column "sid" and "tid" ? And sid isn't just article.getSid() ?

Comment: Yes, it is. I just want to expose the foriegn key in field.So I can seialize the object easier.

Comment: Ok try to not put this field in the database and make setter filling sid when you create the your object. I edit my answer to show you an example.

Comment: But, if I set a sid or pid to `Comment`,then save it, both of sid and pid will not save to db, right ?

Comment: the sid or the pid is exactly the same information than Article and parent. Normally you shouldn't have twice an information in a database. So from the begining, there is something wrong in what you want to do. I think the real question is why do you need this 2 fields. You should think about how change that.