# Ormlite - change name of foreign key column

Tags: ormlite

Is it possible to specify the name of the foreign key in OrmLite?

I have two tables

```
public class Order extends BaseData
{

    @DatabaseField(id = true)
    private Long order_ID;


    ...

    @ForeignCollectionField(eager = true, maxEagerForeignCollectionLevel = 2)
    private ForeignCollection<Vehicle> vehicleList;
}


public class Vehicle extends BaseData
{
   @DatabaseField(id = true)
    private long vehicle_ID;


   ...

   @DatabaseField(canBeNull = false, foreign = true)
   private Order order;

}
```

What I'd really like to do is include in the definition of my Vehicle class an order_id and then specify that ormlite uses this order_id as the foreign key field.

I've tried the below:

```
public class Vehicle extends BaseData
{
   @DatabaseField(id = true)
    private long vehicle_ID;

    @DatabaseField
    private long order_ID;

   @DatabaseField(canBeNull = false, foreign = true, columnName = "order_ID")
   private Order order;

}
```

However this gives error messages regarding duplicate columns when creating the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question looks like one of my old answer : [In ormlite, How can I have a foriegn field and a field column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23733036/in-ormlite-how-can-i-have-a-foriegn-field-and-a-field-column/23733162#23733162).

It give you error because you creating 2 tables with the same name.

You shouldn't store the id in the database and put a setter. If you store the id in the database you will have duplicate information in. Just do :

```
public class Vehicle extends BaseData
{
   @DatabaseField(id = true)
    private long vehicle_ID;

    private long order_ID;

   @DatabaseField(canBeNull = false, foreign = true, columnName = "order_ID")
   private Order order;

   public void setOrder(Order order){
        this.order=order;
        order_ID = order.getId();
   }
}
```